# How can I run Apache Tomcat and Node.JS servers at the same time?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat, node.js, server-setup

I'll give you an example of what I want: Let's pretend my domain is domain.com for now. My server machine is a Linux (Ubuntu). I'm currently running Tomcat as my server on ports 80 and 8080. I have Node.JS installed, and I have a Node app. If I run the app on port 3000, and use `curl localhost:3000`, I get my code. But if I launch domain.com:3000, Chrome just says "connecting", and eventually fails to 'connect', though port 80 and 8080 still work. I even tried stopping tomcat, and running Node, but still same results. **How can I run Apache Tomcat server and NodeJS on different ports, for a domain?**

*Note:* I have root/admin SSH access to the Ubuntu server machine, although no physical access. It is an Amazon AWS EC2 Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one or more of several things, I'd go for

- You may not have opened port 3000 in you EC2 Security Group.
- You may not have configured your node.js to listen on your external address.
- You may not have opened port 3000 in your instance firewall.

Comment: @lain,

* I have opened port 3000 in my EC2 Security Group
* I don't know about configuring Node.js to listen on the external address How?
* I don't know anything about instance firewalls.

Comment: Never mind, you were right! It works! I just forgot to open port 3000 in my security group (I had 2 groups, opened it in the wrong one). Thanks @lain!